# How to pass required claims to OpenID identity provider with Azure ACS?

Tags: azure, appfabric, acs, azure-appfabric, accesscontrolservice

When looking at the request urls that Azure ACS generates I can see that ACS includes email, fullname, firstname and lastname as required claims. Further, the fullname attribute is mapped to the `http://axschema.org/namePerson` claim type.

Now I have added [MyOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com) as an Identity Provider. MyOpenID does not recognize the axschema claim, but I have successfully retrieved `http://schema.openid.net/namePerson` from MyOpenID.

The problem is though, even if I add the `http://schema.openid.net/namePerson` claim as a rule related to the MyOpenID Claim Issuer in ACS, the claim will not be included in the request url generated by ACS.

Is there any (hidden) way of configuring a request for this claim to be required? Or even better, change the built-in mapping to use the `schema.openid.net/namePerson` type instead of `axschema.org/namePerson` ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure gets claims via Attribute Exchange which [myOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com/) doesn't support according to this [blog post by Vittorio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/05/19/adding-a-custom-openid-provider-to-acs-with-just-one-line-of-powershell-code.aspx).

There's an interesting discussion on the topic [over here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuresecurity/thread/e24cf462-4ba5-4720-9718-40a6ad205b2c) on the msdn forums.

Comment: I started that thread at the MSDN forums, to get some input from any MS people that do not follow to closely on SO. If you read the whole thing, you'll see that I've used AX with myOpenID with success. As far as I can see, myOpenID supports AX just fine. AX is just a protocol, supported by both ACS and myOpenID. The difference lies in which attributes ACS will ask for, and which attributes myOpenID is capable of serving.